# request-promise within get request response being duplicated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request-promise

I have the below route in my server:

```
//packages
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const rp      = require('request-promise');

//date logic
var today = new Date();
var d = today.getDate();
var m = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var y = today.getFullYear();
if(d<10) {   d = '0'+d } 
if(m<10) {   m = '0'+m } 
today = y + m + d;

//needs error handling 
//retrieve specific ocr records
router.get('/odds/:bid', (req,res,next) => {

    //sports action API connection
    const actionApi = {
        url: `https://api-prod.sprtactn.co/web/v1/scoreboard/${req.params.bid}?date=${today}`,
        json: true
    }

    //home team, away team, opening odds, and closing odds API pul
    rp(actionApi)
        .then((data) => { 

    const games = data.games

        games.forEach((games) => {

            games.teams.forEach((teams, i) => {
                if (games.home_team_id == games.teams[i].id) {
                    homeTeam.push({home_team: games.teams[i].full_name}); 
                } else if (games.away_team_id == games.teams[i].id) {
                    awayTeam.push({away_team: games.teams[i].full_name}); 
                }
            })

            games.odds.forEach((odds, i) => {
                if (games.odds[i].type == "game" && games.odds[i].book_id == "15") {
                    currOdds.push({
                                    currAwayLine: games.odds[i].ml_away, 
                                    currHomeLine: games.odds[i].ml_home, 
                                    currAwaySpread: games.odds[i].spread_away, 
                                    currHomeSpread: games.odds[i].spread_home, 
                                    currAwayTotal: games.odds[i].total,
                                    currHomeTotal: games.odds[i].total,
                                    homeMlBets: games.odds[i].ml_home_public,
                                    awayMlBets: games.odds[i].ml_away_public,
                                    totalOverBets: games.odds[i].total_over_public,
                                    totalUnderBets: games.odds[i].total_under_public,
                                    spreadHomeBets: games.odds[i].spread_home_public,
                                    spreadAwayBets: games.odds[i].spread_away_public
                                })
                } else if (games.odds[i].type == "game" && games.odds[i].book_id == "30") {
                    openOdds.push({
                                    openAwayLine: games.odds[i].ml_away, 
                                    openHomeLine: games.odds[i].ml_home, 
                                    openAwaySpread: games.odds[i].spread_away, 
                                    openHomeSpread: games.odds[i].spread_home,
                                    openAwayTotal: games.odds[i].total,
                                    openHomeTotal: games.odds[i].total
                                })
                } 
            })
        })

            for (i = 0; i < homeTeam.length; i++) {
                mergRecs.push({
                    homeTeam: homeTeam[i].home_team, 
                    awayTeam: awayTeam[i].away_team,
                    currAwayLine: currOdds[i].currAwayLine,
                    currHomeLine: currOdds[i].currHomeLine,
                    openAwayLine: openOdds[i].openAwayLine,
                    openHomeLine: openOdds[i].openHomeLine,
                    currAwaySpread: currOdds[i].currAwaySpread,
                    currHomeSpread: currOdds[i].currHomeSpread,
                    openAwaySpread: openOdds[i].openAwaySpread,
                    openHomeSpread: openOdds[i].openHomeSpread,
                    currAwayTotal: currOdds[i].currAwayTotal,
                    currHomeTotal: currOdds[i].currHomeTotal,
                    openAwayTotal: openOdds[i].openAwayTotal,
                    openHomeTotal: openOdds[i].openAwayTotal,
                    homeMlBets: currOdds[i].homeMlBets,
                    awayMlBets: currOdds[i].awayMlBets,
                    totalOverBets: currOdds[i].totalOverBets,
                    totalUnderBets: currOdds[i].totalUnderBets,
                    spreadHomeBets: currOdds[i].spreadHomeBets,
                    spreadAwayBets: currOdds[i].spreadAwayBets
                })

            }
            res.send(mergRecs)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})


module.exports = router; //make router exportable
```

The request-promise with the get request calls an external API. The request from the external API is then parsed into a simplified payload. The get request the request-promise is wrapped in then returns this reduced payload. The first time you call my get request it returns the payload properly, however once you request it again it returns the same payload multiple times.

I've tried putting a simple response such as "res.send('hello world') in the get request and hello world is returned a normal amount of times. But for some reason my request-promise's payload is duplicated when it's called within the get request. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Below is a screenshot from the console log when calling the get request twice: 
[image]

Comment: Where do you declare `mergRecs` in your code?, And I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, can you show the expected output, and what you're getting?

Comment: `currOdds` - global perhaps? certainly looks like you just keep pushing and pushing and pushing to that one poor global array

Comment: That's what I'm thinking @JaromandaX

Comment: oh yeah, there's at least **FIVE** "globals" that are never "cleared" - `mergRecs`, `currOdds`, `openOdds`, `homeTeam` and `awayTeam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're defining `mergRecs`, `openOdds`, `homeTeam` & `currOdds` outside of `router.get('/odds/:bid', () => {}`

And every request keeps pushing to that array, that's why the response is being "duplicated".

You need to declare those arrays inside the callback.

```
router.get('/odds/:bid', (req,res,next) => {
    const mergeRecs = [];
    const currOdds = [];
    const openOdds = [];
    const homeTeam = [];
    /* ... */
});
```

```js
const mergRecs = [];
function badMiddleware() {
  // mergRecs needs to be declared here
  mergRecs.push('yes');
  console.log(mergRecs);
}

badMiddleware(); // 1 yes
badMiddleware(); // 2 yes
badMiddleware(); // 3 yes
```

---

That's only the beginning of your problems. It look like you may be accessing undefined index of `currOdds` & `openOdds`, since I doubt that those two arrays have the same length as `homeTeam`. And if they do, it would seem like you are being very lucky.

Comment: may want to look at how `currOdds`, `openOdds`, `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` are used as well!!!

Comment: Yeah, I see a lot of access to those variables, that may not exist.

Comment: Thank you! I originally defined my variables in the server file and I never moved them to my route. Runs perfectly now!

Comment: Check my updated answer, your code may fail in the future. I don't know the exact output of that API, but it doesn't look good to me.

Comment: do you mean in regards to the "badModdleware" pieces?

Comment: I mean that you're relying on 3 different arrays, filled in different loops, in differents conditions to be the exact same length. those being: `currOdds`, `openOdds` & `homeTeam`